# Stop function execution from another function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following example:

```
function foo1 (callback) {

    if (!foo2(callback)) {
        return;
    }

    console.log("Doing something");
    /* do something */
}

function foo2 (callback) {
    return callback ();
}

foo1 (function () {
     console.log ("Hello World!");
});
```

I want to remove the `if` from `foo1`. Can I stop `foo1` execution calling `foo2`? I am looking for something like this:

```
function foo1 (callback) {

    foo2(callback); // calling foo2 this way I want to prevent
                    // the console.log below to be executed

    console.log("Doing something");
    /* do something */
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Note that I don't want to throw an error. I just want to call the callback function and to stop the function execution.

### Use case

Instead of this:

```
 function a (options, callback) {

     callback = callback || function () {};
     if (typeof callback !== "function") {
         callback = function (err) { console.log (err); }
     }

     if (!options.someField || options.someField.constructor !==  Object) {
         return callback ("someField should be an object");
     }

     /* do something */
 }
```

I want to have:

```
 function a (options, callback) {

     validateFunction (callback, callback);
     validateObject (options, callback);
     validateObject (options.somField, callback);

     /* do something */
 }
```

If one of the `validate*` functions fails it should send the error via `callback` and stop `a` function execution.

Comment: very weird, post a real example...

Comment: @GabrielLlamas Hope it's clear now.

Comment: What do you think is the problem with using if statement?

Comment: @Esailija The same code appears in all functions when I validate the fields.

Comment: I think all your problems would disappear with promises

Comment: @Esailija Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use [promises](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird):

```
 function a (options) {
     return validateObject(options).then(function(){
         return validateObjecT(options.somField);
     }).then(function(){
          return validateObjecT2(options.somField);
     }).then(function(){
          return validateObjecT3(options.somField);
     }).then(function(){
          return validateObjecT4(options.somField);
     }).then(function(){
          /*do something*/
     });
 }

 var validateObject = Promise.method(function(object) {
      // Because this is inside Promise.method, thrown error
      // will be equal to return Promise.reject(new Error("invalid"));
      if (typeof object !== "object") throw new Error("invalid");
 });
```

---

Alternatively function a can be also done like this:

```
function a (options) {
 // If any validation fails, the do something is skipped
 // and the code resumes at the next .catch() with the validation
 // error passed as parameter
 return Promise.all([
    validateObject(options),
    validateObject2(options),
    validateObject3(options),
    validateObject4(options),
    validateObject(options)
 ]).then(function(){
    /*do something*/
 })
}
```

---

```
 a({}).then(function() {
    // Validation succeeded and everything was done
 }).catch(function(e) {
    // Validation or something else failed, e is the rejection error
 });
```

Btw don't use strings as errors, a [string is not an error](http://www.devthought.com/2011/12/22/a-string-is-not-an-error/).

That is, never do:

```
throw "foo";
callback("foo");
reject("foo") // When using promises
```

Instead do:

```
throw new Error("foo");
callback(new Error("foo"));
reject(new Error("foo")) // When using promises
```

Comment: +1, looks good. But the issue is: can I put `/* do something */` code out of the `then` callback? It would be very easy to provide a callback function to `validateObject` function.

Comment: @IonicăBizău no but there is no benefit of having the code outside then, it will still be flat even if it's inside then.

Comment: Just to avoid entering in the *callback hell*. I try to prevent indentation if that's possible.

Comment: @IonicăBizău the code will be flat even if code is inside then i.e. no callback hell

Comment: Please post an example with 4 validations.

Comment: @IonicăBizău also in this case, Promise.all could also be used, check the alternative

Comment: You convinced me. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I invite you to [follow me on GitHub](https://github.com/IonicaBizau). Hope you will like my projects. :-)

Comment: @IonicăBizău checking them out :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, use [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

```
function foo2(callback) {
    // do what you want to do
    throw true;
}
```

And then [catching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) it

```
try {
   foo1();
}
catch (e) {
   // if false, real error, 
}
```

But it appears at a strange design. I hope that you have a valid reason and that it's clear to others whom is reviewing your code in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `if` statements:

```
function a (options, callback) {

    if (!validateFunction (callback)) return;
    if (!validateObject (options, callback)) return;
    if (!validateObject (options.somField, callback)) return;

    /* do something */
}
```

where the `validateFunction` function does not necessarily need 2 parameters if you call it always from such a scenario and the `validate...` functions always return a `boolean` with the result of the validation AND calling the callback in case of error.

```
function validateObject (options, errorCallback) {

    if (!options.someField || options.someField.constructor !==  Object) {
        errorCallback("someField should be an object");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

As many purists say, building an execution flow using `try catch` is not the right thing to do. There is also the performance issue. Using `try catch` is [less performant](http://jsperf.com/try-catch-performance-overhead) then the control statements (e.g. `if`)

And there is though a `try catch` version that is faster and produces less code but I still don't prefer it because it is less clear in the code:

```
function a (options, callback) {

    try {
        validateFunction (callback);
        validateObject (options);
        validateObject (options.someField);
    catch (err) {
        callback(err);
        return;
    }

    /* do something */
}

function validateObject (options, errorCallback) {
    if (!options.someField || options.someField.constructor !==  Object) {
        throw "someField should be an object";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a boolean for your function

```
function foo1(callback, exe) {

    if (exe) {
        foo2(callback);
    } else {
        console.log("Doing something");
        /* do something */
    }
}
```